# Design pattern to coordinate behavior of multiple editable UI widgets on the same Model?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

Suppose (this is a hypothetical scenario from concrete scenarios I've come across multiple times) I have a Model which represents a single numerical value, the current_time of a video player. I create three UI elements that both display and edit this value:

- A slider
- A textfield
- A custom view that displays a series of stills which can be clicked on

I also have a "play" button that starts up a process that periodically updates the current time. I also have the video view itself, that displays what it needs to display based on the current time (if this is not how video players work, please accept the hypothetical).

So in MV* Observer pattern style, all 4 UI elements observe current_time and get notified when it changes and update themselves accordingly.

I also add controllers for each of the 3 editable elements, which have a change listener to capture user input and modify the model.

What are my options for avoiding various kinds of "re entry":

- When I modify the slider, the model is changed, the UI elements are notified and updated - so they want to fire change events, which should be prevented at some level, but where?
- When I modify the slider, the model is changed, the slider is one of the UI elements that gets notified, but it doesn't need updating - where do I prevent it from doing that?
- Suppose I make a very robust model updater that validates and parses a lot of inputs. So the textfield could send "2mn 10s" and the model will update itself accordingly and notify all observers - and in this case, the textfield a) should update itself (to show "130") and b) should still not fire a change event

This could be solved by differentiating "programmatic change" from user input change - but it requires all widgets have consistent behavior - or have custom controllers which behave differently according to the widget. Also, there are rare cases where I might not have any choice but to programmatically update as a proxy for a user input.

I am tempted to let the views update all they want, trigger all the change events they want and either have the controllers check with the model that it needs changing, or even have the model decide whether it really changed before notifying its observers. But this lets a lot of ultimately useless calls happen.

I feel like this is a problem that can be and has been consistently solved in two or three design pattern ways, but google is coming up a blank.

Comment: I get a feeling that you are referring to [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) as "models". Aside from that, you probably will want to learn about [presentation objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html), which might give you some directions for solving your problem.

Comment: As near as I can tell, in this context, I want my domain objects to behave as models, so I'm not sure there is much of a difference referring to them as the one or the other (although technically, yes I did mean domain object). I knew about presentation objects (what I'm calling a controller could be a presentation object, a view model, or other kind of user input handling/coordinating system) - the question of change triggering cycles still remains. But I'm super happy to see that in that example, Fowler specifically describes where he prevents synchronisation from triggering cycles. Thanks!